# Как программно пройтись по значениям в TreeTableView?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

JavaFX. Пишу программу, столкнулся с проблемой, есть кнопка по которой заполняется TreeTableView, по нажатии по другой нужно к определенной записи добавлять элемент, еще одна загвоздка в том что, элементы в TreeTableView добавляется асинхронно, т.е. процесс добавления постоянный при некотором событии. код добавления

```
rfid.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(new DataRfid(_rfid_id, _main)));
```

может к TreeItem можно сразу как-то привязывать ID, и уже по нему находить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы можете обойти рекурсирвно все элементы и найти нужный по `_rfid_id` :

```
private TreeItem < DataRfid > find(TreeItem < DataRfid > root, int rfidId) {
    if (root.getValue()._rfid_id == rfidId) {
        return root;
    }
    for (TreeItem < DataRfid > child: root.getChildren()) {
        TreeItem < DataRfid > find = find(child, rfidId);
        if (find != null) {
            return find;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Данный метод вернет первый `TreeItem`, у которого будет `_rfid_id` равный переданному `rfidId`, или `null`, если такого `TreeItem` не существует.